# Trying to get a number within an array that is twice the average 

Tags: c++

I have been  assigned to set up an array with points. I am told to get the  maximum value,  average, and within this same array, if any point in the array is twice the average, I should `cout` an "outlier." So far I have  gotten the average and maximum numbers in the array. but i am unable to set the programme to `cout` the outlier. Instead it gives me  a multiple of the average.
here is the programme;

```
int main()
{
    const int max = 10;
    int ary[max]={4, 32, 9, 7, 14, 12,  13, 17, 19, 18};
    int i,maxv;
    double out,sum=0;
    double av;


    maxv= ary[0];

    for(i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        if(maxv<ary[i])
            maxv= ary[i];

    }
    cout<<"maximum value: "<<maxv<<endl;

    for(i=0; i<max; i++)
    {

        sum = sum + ary[i];
        av = sum / max;
    }
    cout<<"average: "<<av<<endl;

    out = av * 2;

    if(ary[i]>out)
    {
        cout<<"outlier:  "<<maxv<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"ok"<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your work!  I see most homework style questions posted here with just the question and the expectation that the community will solve it for them.  This shows that you have put thought into it and would like help on certain aspects of the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Worth noting that the line `av = sum / max` can be moved outside the loop. Right now you are first computing the average of the first 1 elements, then the average of the first 2 elements, then the average of the first 3... on the last iteration through you compute the average of the first 10 elements (i.e. all of the elements), and then after the loop is over, you output this last computation.

Answer (score 10):

Your code contains a subtle and tricky to spot bug. You're using ary[i] after the final for loop. At this point, the value of i is equal to max, so your if statement is comparing random memory because you're going off the end of the array.

Since this is C++ and not C, you could have avoided this particular bug by declaring your loop variables in the for loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: And it's a good habit: always declare your variables in the tighter scope possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a C++ solution to your assignment, but you probably won't be allowed to hand that in ;-)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int ary[N] = {4, 32, 9, 7, 14, 12, 13, 17, 19, 18};

    int max = *std::max_element(ary, ary + N);
    std::cout << "maximum: " << max << std::endl;

    double average = std::accumulate(ary, ary + N, 0.0) / N;
    std::cout << "average: " << average << std::endl;

    std::cout << "outlier: ";
    std::remove_copy_if(ary, ary + N,
                        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
                        std::bind2nd(std::less_equal<double>(), 2 * average));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: When you look at it, c++ is such an ugly language.

Comment: i dunno, wrap it / declare using std namespace, and I think it looks fairly good and very similar to reading english (but I'm biased so...)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use two for-loops.  You should be traversing the `ary` and checking each element against `out`, then `cout << ary[i]`.

This would probably be a little more obvious if you declared your variables where they are used, in the smallest scope possible.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; ...) {
}
```

and

```
double outlier = avg * 2;
```

By the way, this may be a little over-your-head (right now), but STL provides functions for determining the `max` [(max_element)](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/max_element.html) and `sum` [(accumulate)](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html) of an array.  It might be interesting reading.

Comment: I am assuming this is homework. Some teachers don't really like to see someone that use stuff they haven't thought. He also should learn how the algorithms are written. It's pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

If it is exactly twice the average it should be '==' instead of bigger then twice the avarage.
Aslo why are you outputing `maxv`? Try to use more meaningful names.
Shouldn't you print `ary[i]` instead?
Also, why aren't you looping the array again with a for loop? Shouldn't you iterate all over it to find all outliners or should only the last element be checked for an outliner.

Comment: Technically you're correct, but I think the term "outlier" indicates that it should be "bigger than twice the average".

Answer (score 0):

I prepared the following program (mostly for my own learning). It attempts to make as much use of the C++ Standard Library as possible.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<float> nums;
  // this will read the numbers from standard input; it will continue
  // for as long as it can read floats (to stop you can enter a
  // letter, or press Ctrl+D)
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<float>(std::cin),
            std::istream_iterator<float>(),
            std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<float>>(nums));

  // calculate the mean
  float mean = std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0) / nums.size();

  std::cout<<"Mean of "<<nums.size()<<" numbers: "<<mean<<std::endl;

  // create a lambda function which returns true if a number is BELOW
  // twice the mean
  auto fun = [&mean](float x) {return x < 2.0 * mean;};

  // partition the list of numbers: those for which the lambda is true
  // (i.e., the ones BELOW twice the man) will come before the
  // outliers; the stable sort ensures that within each partition the
  // numbers come in the original order
  auto mark = std::stable_partition(nums.begin(), nums.end(), fun);

  // mark gives an iterator to the first element of the second
  // partition; it it is before the end we report the outliers
  if(mark!=nums.end()) {

    std::cout<<"Found "<<nums.end()-mark<<" outliers:"<<std::endl;

    for(auto it=mark; it!=nums.end(); ++it) {
      std::cout<<"\t"<<*it<<std::endl;
    }

  } else {
    std::cout<<"No outliers found."<<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My output (compiled with `g++` (GCC 4.7.2) using the `-std=c++11` flag).

```
[Prompt] ./a.out
1 2 3 4 5 20 f # the f is to end the stream of numbers; press enter
Mean of 6 numbers: 5
Found 1 outliers:
    20
```